# Sound doesnt work in newest kernel, but works in 2.6.33 kernel?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, sound, kernel

When I install the 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx kernel on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system, sound works fine.

But if I use newest kernel of 12.04, it shows my audio hardware but plays no sound.

I don't want use the old kernel, because I think I cannot use some software, including GNOME 3, with it. Or at least they didn't work when I tested the old kernel, and the screen resolution was low.

I also tried newer kernels but only 2.6.33 worked without any sound problems.

My sound card is a Realtek HD ATI ALC1200 integrated card. My front jack is broken and it detects that something is always plugged in--does this affect my situation?

Do I have to buy a new sound card? That would suck.

Comment: Did you upgrade Ubuntu from 10.04, or did you install kernel 3.2.0 in 10.04?

Comment: Yes.  Jack-sense could be breaking you.  Can't you just disconnect the front-panel jack?

Comment: @takkat I had 10.04, but I wiped it away and made a clean install of 12.04. I installed 10.04's kernel in 12.04.

Comment: @aking1012 This is strange. I unplugged the front panels cable, but still no sound from my system. Any Ideas?

Comment: I'ld try jumping and un-jumping the connector.  This would be to try and force a jack-sense of removing the headphones.  I had a similar issue once, but it wasn't a broken jack.  It was an Intel HDA bug(which has since been fixed).

Comment: @Kimmo69 Could you add the answer as an answer now that you've solved the problem, rather than including it in the actual question :)

Comment: I fixed this problem by going to alsamixer. There was this thing called "automute-mode" and it was enabled. By disabling it, my sound started working again. I think this had something to do with my broken front jack.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster was able to solve the problem as follows (moved from being an edit to the question, to here):

> I fixed this problem by going to alsamixer. There was this thing
>   called "automute-mode" and it was enabled. By disabling it, my sound
>   started working again. I think this had something to do with my broken
>   front jack.